# Minimize all windows

Tags: batch-file

i can get the actual batch windows to minimise but not the iexplore window, i

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo http://www.suffolkweather.info/flatline-check.php
start/min cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.suffolkweather.info/flatline-check.php

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 -l 0
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe /t
```

Comment: There is no need for `CMD /c`. `start /min iexplore http://www.suffolkweather.info/flatline-check.php`. Although that web address doesn't work.

Comment: What is your aim for doing like that ? what do you get from this link ? perhaps there is another way to it in vbscript ?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch :

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo "http://www.suffolkweather.info/flatline-check.php"
start "" /min "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.suffolkweather.info/flatline-check.php"
Call :ShellMinimizeAll vbsfile.vbs
pause
Exit /b
:ShellMinimizeAll
(
echo ShellMinimizeAll
echo Function ShellMinimizeAll
echo    dim objShell
echo    set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application"^)
echo    objShell.MinimizeAll
echo    set objShell = nothing
echo End function
)>%1
cscript /nologo %1
Del %1
Exit /b
```

Comment: The extra cmd.exe was probable cause of problem. That's a good tip using vbscript to minimise all applications. Useful for case where the started application has code manipulating window during startup. You could also add code to restore specific window if you know the window's title.  It is possible a web page could be doing javascript code to give window focus. That kind of javascript in older IE versions may restore window but usually it will only cause taskbar entry to flash.  Also put an `exit /b` after `pause`.